# Bing search API with DisableLocationDetection not working

Tags: bing, bing-api

The Bing search API is using my (or my server's) location even when I set the appropriate option. I would like it to provide a location agnostic response.

Am I misunderstanding the documentation? Is this syntax right?

```
http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid=<XXX>&query=microsoft&sources=news&options=DisableLocationDetection
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is right. According to the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251023.aspx), the `DisableLocationDetection` option prevents Bing from inferring location from the query itself ("microsoft" in your example), but not from the properties of the request, such as server's IP.

News requests can specify [LocationOverride parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250901.aspx) to get news from a particular US state. Also, if you're having troubles with automatic market detection (if your server is in another country, for example), you can specify [Market parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251064.aspx) to override the market detection.

If this still doesn't help you, can you update the question to provide an example of a query which gives you the bad result?